# problem with resolving apache math4 library in scala

Tags: scala, build, sbt

I created a simple Scala project to use with apache commons-math4 dependency. The content of build.sbt is the following.

```
name := "math4test"
version := "0.1"
scalaVersion := "3.0.2"

resolvers += ("apache_snapshots" at "https://repository.apache.org/content/repositories/snapshots/").withAllowInsecureProtocol(true)
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.commons" % "commons-math4" % "4.0-SNAPSHOT"
```

The sbt fails to resolve a number of dependencies for math4:

```
[error] (update) sbt.librarymanagement.ResolveException: Error downloading org.apache.commons:commons-numbers-rootfinder:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[error]   Not found
```

Comment: Do you really want to depend on snapshot versions?!

Answer (score 2):

You should not rely on SNAPSHOT dependencies: they are not stable, don't provide a reproducible build and are not kept forever on repositories.

At the time of writing this answer, the latest published version `4.0-SNAPSHOT` of commons-math4 depends on a version `1.0-SNAPSHOT` of commons-numbers-rootfinder which is not available anymore (`1.1-SNAPSHOT` does exist: https://repository.apache.org/content/repositories/snapshots/org/apache/commons/commons-numbers-rootfinder/).

Comment: I heard that many programmers switched to math4 that is available only as a snapshot. I guess I should stick with math3 for now.

Comment: @mark if the answer suits you, you can mark it as accepted ;)